# How to run a .sh file that has hdiutil, sudo, and wget for Visual Studio Code(windows)?

Tags: windows, vagrant, wget

Currently I'm stuck at figuring out why a .sh script isn't running:

```
export DOWNLOAD_LOCATION=~/Downloads/
export VAGRANT_URL=https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/2.2.6/vagrant_2.2.6_x86_64.dmg
export VIRTUALBOX_URL=https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.2/VirtualBox-6.1.2-135662-OSX.dmg

echo "===== Install Vagrant ====="

wget $VAGRANT_URL -P $DOWNLOAD_LOCATION
hdiutil attach $DOWNLOAD_LOCATION"vagrant_2.2.6_x86_64.dmg"
sudo installer -pkg /Volumes/Vagrant/vagrant.pkg -target /

echo "===== Install VirtualBox ====="

wget $VIRTUALBOX_URL -P $DOWNLOAD_LOCATION
hdiutil attach $DOWNLOAD_LOCATION"VirtualBox-6.1.2-135662-OSX.dmg"
sudo installer -pkg /Volumes/VirtualBox/virtualbox.pkg -target /

echo "===== Install MiniKF ====="
vagrant init arrikto/minikf
vagrant up
```

Windows is telling that:

```
./install.sh: line 9: wget: command not found
./install.sh: line 10: hdiutil: command not found
./install.sh: line 11: sudo: command not found
```

I have wget installed in Visual studio, do I need to install it for windows?

Comment: This script is designed for macOS. I doubt it makes sense on Windows or Linux.

Comment: Yea, I just noticed that it was for MacOS.  Thank you for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

> why a .sh script isn't running

It is calling commands, which are not available, namely `wget`, `hdiutil`, `sudo`.

There exist [GNU Wget](https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/) for Windows, which is `wget.exe` file and after placing in current working directory calls for `wget` and `wget.exe` should work, however `hdiutil` is more important here. My cursory search did not unveil `hdiutil` for Windows, so even if you make `wget` working you still need find some way to use `.dmg` file in your Windows system.